# if i change my width screen 2 - 4 mores, the code cant run without refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if ($(window).width() < 900) {
    $("#responsive_content_1").removeClass("justify-content-center d-flex");
    $("#responsive_content_1_1").addClass("center");
    $("#responsive_features").removeClass("justify-content-center d-flex");
    $(".text_features").removeClass("col-3").addClass("col mt-3 margin-text");
    $(".hide").hide();
}

if ($(window).width() > 900) {
    $("#responsive_content_1").addClass("justify-content-center d-flex");
    $("#responsive_content_1_1").removeClass("center");
    $("#responsive_features").addClass("justify-content-center d-flex");
    $(".text_features").addClass("col-3").removeClass("col mt-3 margin-text");
    $(".hide").show();
}
```

I have problem here, if I change my screen 2-4 with inspect element the code can't run again. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please explain `code can't run again`. Also I suggest to add your code to `setTimeout` to prevent re-run on every width pixel changed

Comment: Yes, make a function with all of these code (like `resizeFunction()`) and ejecute it every time you resize the window. `$( window ).resize(function() {`

Comment: where you have enclosed this code as it will execute once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the window `resize` event:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
 if ($(window).width() < 900) {
       $("#responsive_content_1").removeClass("justify-content-center d-flex");
        $("#responsive_content_1_1").addClass("center");
    $("#responsive_features").removeClass("justify-content-center d-flex");
    $(".text_features").removeClass("col-3").addClass("col mt-3 margin-text");
    $(".hide").hide();


 }

 if ($(window).width() > 900) {

    $("#responsive_content_1").addClass("justify-content-center d-flex");
    $("#responsive_content_1_1").removeClass("center");
    $("#responsive_features").addClass("justify-content-center d-flex");
    $(".text_features").addClass("col-3").removeClass("col mt-3 margin-text");
    $(".hide").show();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(window).resize()`
https://api.jquery.com/resize/

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
   //ALL YOUR CODE AGAIN
})
```

I recommend to make a `function` with all your code, and execute the function when `$(document).ready` and when `$(window).resize`